# Will a short time period for SyncAdapter's periodic sync, necessarily drain the battery?

Tags: android

In this case, "short time period" can be 30 seconds up 5 minutes.
My `onPerformSync` method does almost nothing most of the times, but I'm concerned that the short sync period might prevent the phone from sleeping, and have a drastic effect on battery life.

```
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {

    if (!InternetConnectionDetector.isConnectedToInternet())
        return;

    if (/*We have received a push from server indicating update is available*/)
        syncWithServer();
    else
        return;

}
```

Comment: If you are saying you want to be syncing every 30 seconds, AFAIK `SyncAdapter` is not a good solution for that. Also, bear in mind that on Android M, your syncs will not occur if the device is in doze mode (most of the day for many devices) or if your app is placed into app standby mode.

Comment: It won't be as short as 30 seconds all the time, more towards the 5 minutes end most of the times. What other options do I have other than `SyncAdapter` for this purpose? And thanks for the notice about doze mode. I checked that out. I think that won't be a problem in this case.

Comment: "What other options do I have other than SyncAdapter for this purpose?" -- well, it sounds like you are doing this while you are in the foreground, in which case you just do the network calls as part of your app. AFAIK, `SyncAdapter` is for when you want synchronization to be done when your app is not otherwise running, as part of other apps on the device doing synchronization. I've never used it, as it's tied up in lots of other icky APIs. If I want background even-if-the-app-is-not-running processing, I use `AlarmManager`.

Answer (score 0):

Sync adapter will run at specific interval depends on Android system optimization even if you define frequency in your code. From Android 6.0 and above app prevent run sync adapter when device is idle/standby or sleeping/doze mode.
Doze mode optimized to improve battery performance and same for standby.
While android system in doze or standby mode it's prevent to run sync adapyer, sync job, sync scheduler, alarm. 
Its gives chance to run all these background that specific interval that we call maintainance window.  This maintenance window perform all pending sync. Initially this window open frequently and later interval get longer in each maintainance window.

If you still want to perform background task irrespective of doze or standby mode you can use priority firebase message to run sync or seek permission from user to perform better intensive task. For mode details refer android developer docs about doze mode and stand by mode